# Transform PHP array into JSON Format for NEO4J query via HTTP API

Tags: php, json, neo4j

I want to query the Neo4J database via CURL - the API expects a JSON format like this:

```
{"statements" : [{"statement" : "MATCH (n) RETURN COUNT(n) AS number;"} ]}
```

I have an issue with the combination of the brackets: [{ }]

I come close with this code:

```
$array['statements'] = 
 (array['statement'] = ('MATCH (n) RETURN COUNT(n) AS number;'))

$data = json_encode($array);
```

This produces the output:

```
{"statements":[["statement","MATCH (n) RETURN COUNT(n) AS number;"]]}
```

I need advice how to change the 2nd inner pair of square brackets to curly ones - someone has a hint?
Thank you

Comment: ```$array['statements'][]->statement = 'MATCH (n) RETURN COUNT(n) AS number;';``` Guess you could do it this way? But it seems strange :D It gives you: ```{"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (n) RETURN COUNT(n) AS number;"}]}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing I've seen in this question/thread looks sane/runnable.

Basics:

- `{}` is a JSON object, equivalent to a PHP associative array.
- `[]` is a JSON array, equivalent to a PHP numerically-indexed array.

So:

```php
$foo = [
  'statements' => [
    [ 'statement' => 'MATCH (n) RETURN COUNT(n) AS number;' ]
  ]
];

$foo_json = json_encode($foo);
```

Result:

```json
{"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (n) RETURN COUNT(n) AS number;"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help - I didnt knew the notation of array in PHP you used - a shame :) That helped very much.